# Using GNU-style long options in argparse (not confusing optional argument with positional)

Tags: python, argparse

For example with GNU `ls` you can control coloring by using the `--color[=WHEN]` option. Now in this case the equal sign is crucial since `ls` have to distinguish between an optional argument to `--color` and positional arguments (which is the files to list). That is `ls --color` lists file with colors, which is the same as `ls --color=always`, but `ls --color always` will list the file `always` (and with colors).

Now from what I've seen `argparse` seem to accept arguments to long options using the `--longopt <argument>` syntax as well which will lead to not being able to make the argument optional. That is if I try to implement `myls` with the same behavior as GNU `ls` (that's just an example) I would run into problems as now `myls --color always` means the same as `myls --color=always` (and not as required `--color` without argument and `always` as a positional argument).

I know that I can circumvent this by using `myls --color -- always`, but isn't there a way to make this work without that workaround? That is to tell `argparse` that the argument to `--color` has to be supplied with the `--color[=WHEN]` syntax.

Note that I don't want to rely on the fact that the `--color` option has finite number of valid arguments. Here's an example what I've tried that didn't work properly:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("--foo",
                    action="store",
                    nargs="?")
parser.add_argument("frob",
                    action="store",
                    nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)

print(parser.parse_args(["alpha", "beta"]))
print(parser.parse_args(["--foo", "alpha", "beta"]))
print(parser.parse_args(["--foo=bar", "alpha", "beta"]))
```

With the output:

```
Namespace(foo=None, frob=['alpha', 'beta'])
Namespace(foo='alpha', frob=['beta'])
Namespace(foo='bar', frob=['alpha', 'beta'])
```

note the second where `alpha` was interpreted as argument to `--foo`. I wanted:

```
Namespace(foo=None, frob=['alpha', 'beta'])
Namespace(foo=None, frob=['alpha', 'beta'])
Namespace(foo='bar', frob=['alpha', 'beta'])
```

Comment: is it possible to workaround by add two arguments? One for "--color", and another that is  "--color=always". I dont have a terminal available right now to test.

Comment: I've worked out a patch that requires minor surgery to `argparse.py`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've probably already tried the `?` optional followed by required positional:

```
 p=argparse.ArgumentParser()
 p.add_argument('--foo', nargs='?',default='one', const='two')
 p.add_argument('bar')
```

which fails with

```
In [7]: p.parse_args('--foo 1'.split())
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--foo [FOO]] bar
ipython3: error: the following arguments are required: bar
```

`--foo` consumes the `1`, leaving nothing for `bar`.

http://bugs.python.org/issue9338 discusses this issue.  The `nargs='?'` is greedy, consuming an argument, even though the following positional requires one.  But the suggested patch is complicated, so I can't quickly apply it to a parser and test your case.

The idea of defining an Action that would work with `--foo==value`, but not consume `value` in  `--foo value`, is interesting, but I have no idea of what it would take to implement.  Certainly it doesn't work with the current parser.  I'd have to review how it handles that explicit `=`.

============================

By changing a deeply nested function in `parse_args`,

```
    def consume_optional(....):
        ....
                # error if a double-dash option did not use the
                # explicit argument
                else:
                    msg = _('ignored explicit argument %r')
                    #raise ArgumentError(action, msg % explicit_arg)
                    # change for stack40989413
                    print('Warn ',msg)
                    stop = start_index + 1
                    args = [explicit_arg]
                    action.nargs=None
                    action_tuples.append((action, args, option_string))
                    break
```

and adding a custom Action class:

```
class MyAction(myparse._StoreConstAction):
    # requies change in consume_optional
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        if values:
            setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)
        else:
            setattr(namespace, self.dest, self.const)
```

I can get the desired behavior from:

```
p = myparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('--foo', action=MyAction, const='C', default='D')
p.add_argument('bar')
```

Basically I'm modifying `store_const` to save the `=explicit_arg` if present.

I don't plan on proposing this as a formal patch, but I'd welcome feedback if it is useful.  Use at your own risk. :)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is not possible. This behaviour is supported by GNU getopt() (`man getopt`, `man 3 getopt`). `man getopt` says:

> If the [long] option has an optional argument, it must be written directly after the long  option name, separated by '=', if present

The Python `getopt` module, however, is clear that it doesn't support this:

> Optional arguments [in long options] are not supported.

For `argparse` I don't find any specific reference in the manual, but I would be surprised if it supported it. In fact, I'm surprised GNU getopt supports it and that `ls` works the way you described. User interfaces should be simple, and this behaviour is far from simple.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm afraid that this is the correct answer (unless there's a clever/stupid/ugly workaround)...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("files", nargs="*", help="List of files", type=str)
parser.add_argument('--color', dest='color', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--color=ALWAYS', dest='color_always', action='store_true')

args = parser.parse_args()
print args
```

Results:

```
[~]$ ./test.py xyz --color
Namespace(color=True, color_always=False, files=['xyz'])
[~]$ ./test.py xyz --color=ALWAYS
Namespace(color=False, color_always=True, files=['xyz'])
```

Comment: In this particular example that would work, but it's not feasible if it wasn't a finite number of valid arguments. Take for example if one long option had an optional path argument.

Comment: Yes, I couldn't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

**Problemo solved!**
It's a bit (a lot) hacky, but here you go.

The solution revolves around a class that inherits _StoreConstAction and tweaks it a little, but mainly tricks the help formatter when it tries to get its attributes.

I tested this in python3 under windows and linux.

```py
import argparse
import inspect

class GnuStyleLongOption(argparse._StoreConstAction):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        self._real_option_strings = kw['option_strings']
        opts = []
        for option_string in self._real_option_strings:
            opts.append(option_string)
            for choice in kw['choices']:
                opts.append(f'{option_string}={choice}')
        kw['option_strings'] = opts
        self.choices = kw.pop('choices')
        help_choices = [f"'{choice}'" for choice in self.choices]
        kw['help'] += f"; {kw['metavar']} is {', or '.join([', '.join(help_choices[:-1]), help_choices[-1]])}"
        super(GnuStyleLongOption, self).__init__(**kw)

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        caller_is_argparse_help = False
        for frame in inspect.stack():
            if frame.function == 'format_help' and frame.filename.endswith('argparse.py'):
                caller_is_argparse_help = True
                break

        if caller_is_argparse_help:
            if attr == 'option_strings':
                return [f'{i}[=WHEN]' for i in self._real_option_strings]
            if attr == 'nargs':
                return 0
            if attr == 'metavar':
                return None

        return super(GnuStyleLongOption, self).__getattribute__(attr)

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, self.const if '=' not in option_string else option_string[option_string.find('=') + 1:])

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('--color', '--colour', action=GnuStyleLongOption, choices=['always', 'never', 'auto'], const='always', default='auto', help='use markers to highlight whatever we want', metavar='WHEN')
p.add_argument('filenames', metavar='filename', nargs='*', help='file to process')
args = p.parse_args()

print(f'color = {args.color}, filenames = {args.filenames}')
```

Results:

```
~ $ ./gnu_argparse.py --help
usage: gnu_argparse.py [-h] [--color[=WHEN]] [filename [filename ...]]

positional arguments:
  filename              file to process

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --color[=WHEN], --colour[=WHEN]
                        use markers to highlight whatever we want; WHEN is
                        'always', 'never', or 'auto'

~ $ ./gnu_argparse.py
color = auto, filenames = []

~ $ ./gnu_argparse.py file
color = auto, filenames = ['file']

~ $ ./gnu_argparse.py --color file
color = always, filenames = ['file']

~ $ ./gnu_argparse.py --color never file
color = always, filenames = ['never', 'file']

~ $ ./gnu_argparse.py --color=never file
color = never, filenames = ['file']

~ $ ./gnu_argparse.py --colour=always file
color = always, filenames = ['file']
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe `nargs` would be help.

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--color', nargs='?', const='c', default='d')
>>> parser.parse_args(['XX', '--color', 'always'])
Namespace(bar='XX', color='always')
>>> parser.parse_args(['XX', '--color'])
Namespace(bar='XX', color='c')
>>> parser.parse_args([])
Namespace(bar='d', color='d')
```

with nargs, you get different args and you will know what the input type is.

by the way, I think `--color` option could use `action='store_true'`.

```
parser.add_argument('--color', action='store_true')
```

Comment: That wasn't the problem. The problem was that `--foo always` should be interpreted as `--foo` without an optional argument and `always` should be interpreted as part of the positional arguments. I want to mandate using `--foo` (without argument) or `--foo=always`.

Comment: I'm afraid you've missed my point (I've also updated the question). The problem was that `--color always` should **not** be accepted as meaning `--color=always`.